# What are the IPSE’s, the ASPE’s, the FRIPSE’s and the GRIPSE’s?

Tags: history, identify-this-software

In one of Edsger Dijkstra's most famous essays "[By way of introduction](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD10xx/EWD1041.html)" there is this paragraph:

> As final example of skirting the programming issue I mention “software engineering”, the IPSE’s, the ASPE’s, the FRIPSE’s and the GRIPSE’s and all further animation tools you can think of. They come from a world that has accepted its charter “How to program if you cannot.”. The best of these efforts just confuse composing with the physical act of writing the score, others are foolish at best, and some are criminal.

From the context, it seems like those are some graphical tools from the 80s (the essay is dated 12 Feb 1989), which were used for computer programming education, however I wasn't able to find any information on the Internet about them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
IPSE   = Integrated Project Support Environment
     (or Integrated Programming Support Environment
ASPE   = Ada Programming Support Environment
FRIPSE = Formal Reasoning Integrated Programming Support Environment
GRIPSE = Graphical Integrated Programming Support Environment
```

Keep in mind, Dijkstra's rant is about the formal programming hype of the late 1980s which he didn't consider to be fruitful, wise man he was.

---

Some further links:

- [IPSE](http://www.chilton-computing.org.uk/inf/se/sw/p005.htm)
- The preliminary specification of FRIPSE, KD Jones, 1987
- [MURAL](http://www.chilton-computing.org.uk/inf/se/sw/p004.htm) (as what is FRIPSE known today) (Also [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4471-3180-9))
- [A uniform graphical view of the program construction process: GRIPSE](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020737383710382)
- Some examples can be found in a [1987 paper](http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/cliff.jones/publications/MUCS-TRs/UMCS-87-12-8.pdf) provided by alephzero

When searching, adding *"Formal Verification"* might be helpful, as that was the core idea. After all, programming is just mathematics, right? So it should be possible to program in a way that makes it possible to prove the correctness in an automated, formalized way. Thankfully that's mostly (*1) dead by now.

What does live on is the idea of functional programming as a paradigm, further refining certain ways of design and coding. As so often, what happened, got similarities to the clasic [Hype Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hype_cycle), were above projects where at the forefront of hype, while today we're way into the production plateau. Most high hopes didn't come true as predicted (flying cars) while at the same time realistic application has taken over.

---

As a side note, if there's any writing of his that can be considered *most* famous, then it's his 1968 *"Go To Statement Considered Harmful"*. This one influenced eventually each and every modern programming language (except possibly Brainfuck).

---

*1 - There are languages like Haskel and Erlang that do incooperate and even enforce formal programming due their strict functional style. Still hard to see them becoming mainstream the same way structured languages did.

Comment: +1, I spent too long reading related papers! “ASPE” is a typo in Dijkstra’s note; it should be “APSE”. (See *e.g.* [*The importance of Ada programming support environments*](https://doi.org/10.1145/1500774.1500815).)

Comment: See for example http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/cliff.jones/publications/MUCS-TRs/UMCS-87-12-8.pdf.

Comment: @StephenKitt It was about the time I finally gave up on following any theory. I'm always keen to offload standard tasks of validation and error checking to the machine, so I really tried hard to find any good use for that  approach. What a waste of time. BTW, I love Ada. Next best thing after Assembly.

Comment: @Raffzahn I never got into formal programming either, but I’ve been following Clifford Wolf’s work on formal RISC-V the past few years, he’s getting some really interesting results!

Comment: @StephenKitt Oh, I do belive about a nice for formal proof in hardware development - as long as it can be reduced close enough. Similar there are a few nieces in very special areas of software. Just never a majority, as real world requirements are way too complex. Using formal systems for RL applications always rely on assumptions ad non conclusive reduction, rendering any result worthless. The basic problem with European CS is that programming was seen as a facet of mathematics, not engineering. And formal proof is one of the dead end  developments favoured.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I just want to say that I found your comment about Dijkstra's views on formal verification a bit strange, because for example, the wikipedia article on him has this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra#Formal_specification_and_verification where he is described as a proponent of the usage of formal methods.

Comment: @ArdavastDayleryan Well, doesn't the paragraph you cite imply a less than enthusiastic view on the tools implementing formal verification? Beside doing quite some interesting theoretical work, Dijkstra has always been a proponent that real world usage. And to me this paragraph seams to quite disagree with what wonders are prayed upon formal verification by others.

Comment: Dijkstra's complaint is not about the tools that work, it's about developers not being willing to use them. We've had for at least a couple of decades the ability to tell compilers things like, "generate an error if you can't prove that this function will never return an empty list," but developers mostly don't want to put in the work to learn how to use the languges that support that. Instead, they substitute other tools that claim to help them program better without learning such things.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson sounds like you did read something compete different. I hear someone complaining that people assume that with such tools programs can be written by anyone, replacing the educated programmer by button pressing.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson So what? That's what I said. Either you're just contradicting your own comment again, or there was no reason to write the first one at all. It might really be helpful to read first and try to read with an open mind, not making any understanding impossible by forcing a certain view - see the 'octal' theme as well.

Comment: In your five bulleted "further links", the second bullet has no link.

Comment: @Raffzahn I was replying to your comment about Dijkstra having "a less than enthusiastic view on the tools implementing formal verification," meaning that he doesn't support the use of those tools.Quite the opposite: he does support use of formal verification tools, when actually used as opposed to being "just eyewash" (EWD1036).

Comment: "Thankfully mostly dead by now." Except by functional programmers.

Comment: @EricTowers Jup, I couldn't find any online reference doing more than referencing the title.

Comment: @RonJohn No doubt, there is a nice for everyone. Not even its proponents would attribute Haskel or Erlang as mainstream. Also worth noting, that using a functional programming style (Note the effort the [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) goes to let next to every language  act functional) is far away from the goal of the named historic projects of automatic formal verification. But you're right, I may need to qualify that statement.

Comment: "Still hard to see [Haskel and Erlang] becoming mainstream the same way structured languages did." Except that the ideas embodied by them are becoming mainstream. Functions as data and strict type checking have made their way into many modern languages.

Answer (score 7):

IPSE stands for "Integrated Project Support Environment"; this was one of a series of names given to projects related to using theorm proving in software engineering. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Project_Support_Environment) has a brief blurb on it, but [this Chilton Computing page](http://www.chilton-computing.org.uk/inf/se/sw/p005.htm) offers more detail and probably gives a better sense of what it is and what it does. FRIPSE and GRIPSE were related (FR meaning "formal reasoning" and "GR" meaning "graphical."

If your concern is not about the details of these particular packages at those times but instead what Dijktra was talking about when he mentioned those (certainly any modern example could be substituted in that paper and still preserve what he was trying to say), the [Software Engineering StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) would be a better place for questions.